# Opening New File using VBA on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2011

I am using Excel 2011 for Mac and trying to open a new file.

However, I keep getting an error that file not found even though the file is there. The code I am using is below:

```
Dim theFile As String

theFile = "/Users/Dev/Desktop/RCM/test.xls"
Workbooks.Open FileName:=theFile
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Mac uses a different path separator: switch your "/" to ":"

Comment: Using Users:Dev:Desktop:RCM:test.xls didnt work, neither Mac HD:Users:Dev:Desktop:RCM:test.xls

Comment: If you open the file and make it active what does **Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Path** show?

Answer (score 0):

Make the open line:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="/Users/John/Downloads/File.xlsx"
```